# Using android 86 with virtual box as a smartphone instead of a tablet

Tags: android, virtualbox, android-x86

I am using android-x86 with virtual box . It comes preinstalled with google play store and other services but i can use that iso file with VirtualBox as only as tablet and therefore cannot download some apps from the play store .
I tried changing the resolution but that dont make the emulator screen look like an android smartphone machine. 
How can i use the android-x86 image file as a smartphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) is based on VirtualBox and emulates phones as well as tablets.

Google Apps installation: **https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-install-google-services-on-genymotion/en**

Also - the new Genymotion (2.x) devices are rooted out of the box.

Comment: It does not have google play installed ,no root access and is also not secure as drag and drop is enabled

Comment: Updated my answer. Reagrding security - I don't understand the concept of a "secure" rooted device, and drag-and-drop is not a security issue IMHO,  since it's just a mock download mechanism.

Comment: by "security" i am referring to the security of the host OS at which i am running virtual box .It is recommended to disable the folder sharing and drag and drop to safely use the guest OS in the box on host OS.

Comment: If you see drag-and-drop as a security issue, please do not run Genymotion as an admin: https://www.genymotion.com/faq/#drag-and-drop-impossible. This essentially disables drag and drop

Comment: I believe I have provided you with a good solution to your original post.

Comment: without drag and drop how can i install google play?

Comment: Come on. Use the internal browser to download the files directly from within the emulator.

Comment: genymotion is not free anymore :(